# Make a carousel of every node associated with a term in a particular vocabulary

Tags: views, javascript

I have a vocabulary with a lot of terms in it, I want to show list of each term's nodes as a carousel using views.

I rather using [OwlCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/owlcarousel) module to achieve this.

Can you guide me how to configure the views to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps

- Make a views of taxonomy terms.
- Add a relationship referencing node from that taxonomy terms
- Now you will have the required node fields available in views field
- Add the required field and change the display to carousel.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Yep that's what I thought to do, but it will make every content into a carousel, also I cant use grouping to show them apart.

Comment: So you want to show nodes of only single  term?

Comment: No, consider front page of youtube, how it lists the nodes of every term underneath it, that's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Okay, so you would like to have few nodes in each term. like term1 (node1, node2, node3) term2(node1,node2,node3) and so on.
if this is the case use views_limit_grouping module. It will group your data on your term and limit nodes in each term as well

Comment: yep thx for the suggestion, I tried that, but since that module is a display mode, you cant make that into a carousel as well, considering the fact that you don't want a carousel, what you mentioned will work just fine.

Comment: hmm in that case, use custom way to limit your fields like instead for each in your views tpl use for loop and only show the first 4 or whatever your requirements.